# Help Understanding Equation for Characteristic Time of Induced Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Quv8awSN-RYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=magnetic%20techniques%20for%20the%20treatment%20of%20materials%20pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ePKuUu2lH8yThQfs64D4CA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, the part in particular about Eddy-current separation starting at Page 246, in it there is an equation for calculating the "characteristic time with which the induced magnetic field decays in the particle".

$$
\tau = \mu_0\sigma_psb^2
$$

Where:

- $\mu_0$ is the permeability of free space
- $\sigma_p$ is the specific electric conductivity of a particle [S/m]
- $s$ is the shape factor of the particle
- $b$ is the particle radius

I am hoping someone can reflect some light on what $s$ is and how to calculate it, "shape factor" isn't very descriptive and I cannot find anywhere in the book describing it in further detail.

This shape factor is also used in the force equations that I am intersted in...

Another part of the equation I am unclear on is $b$, what if the particle is a cube or cuboid, what should the radius be then?

Comment: After reading through several papers it appears $b$ is the largest diameter that would fit in the projected shape. I am still unsure about $s$, from what I have read perhaps it is likening the shape to a sphere or cylinder.